# How can I get C# to recognize MM-dd-YY hh:mmtt as a valid datetime format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tryparse

I have a datetime string in the format "MM-dd-YY hh:mmtt". For example: 02-23-21 09:23PM. I am trying to convert this to a DateTime object in C#. I'm using DateTime.TryParseExact() but it keeps failing.

Here is how I'm converting it:

```
var myDateTime = new DateTime();
var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  "02-23-21 09:23PM",
  "MM-dd-YY hh:mmtt",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  DateTimeStyles.None,
  out myDateTime
);
```

TryParseExact() keeps returning false and myDateTime keeps coming out `{0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM}`.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your year format - `yy` is correct one:

```
var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
  "02-23-21 09:23PM",
  "MM-dd-yy hh:mmtt",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  DateTimeStyles.None,
  out myDateTime
);
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yySpecifier):

> The "yy" custom format specifier represents the year as a two-digit number

Comment: Hmm... That's definitely one mistake I was making but it still doesn't work. According to this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.getdatetimeformats?view=net-5.0, my format isn't a valid format even with the lower case y's. But I thought the point of TryParseExact was to indicate your own custom format.

Comment: @gib65 after this change everything works fine for  me - [check it out yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZXoghE). Also not sure what the link you have provided has to do with the question. That method is about standard format strings and we are using a custom one (see the link to the docs in the answer.)